# getting : use of "@import" when modules are disabled when importing Photos

Tags: macos, plugins, phphotolibrary

I am trying to create a plugin for osx using the new photos framework. So I created a new Xcode project (using Version 7.1 (7B91b)), I chose the bundle template under osx and then integrated all my files in the project.

but at the line :

```
@import Photos;
```

I am getting the error : use of "@import" when modules are disabled.

I have looked online and found a lot of people having the same issue with different import. But their solution did not work for me.
Here is what I have tried : 
- Added Photos.Framework in my build phase.
- Enabled module in build settings (Enable Modules(C and Objective-C)).
- Some people suggested to replace @import Photos by #import <....photo.h>, but I do not know which .h file to include like that

So does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Comment: so adding this will compile but most of my variables still are not defined.
#import <Photos/Photos.h> 
PHAssetCollectionSubtype is still not defined.
If I go in xcode and look at the framework headers, I can see under osx 10.11 that there is only like 4 header files, but in Ios 9 there is way more. So I was wondering, could it be that the osx version is not completed yet?